# ASP.Net Idenity - Override FindByName to include extra search criteria

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identity

We have a setup where clients run stand-alone version of our system, but they all link to the same Identity Database with Entity Framework.

A user can be registered as a user on many versions of the application, thereby having multiple accounts with the same username, but the applicationId (stored in the web.config) is unique.

What I would like to do is use the UserManager.FindByName function, but have it automatically add the "&& applicationId = X" to the request sent to the context.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can inherit from the UserManager class, but you have to rewrite the original code (.NET now is open source you can find the original code) and add your logic to it. However, this may be a lengthy action.

What i suggest is if you are using Entity Framework search for the user id by name and application id, then pass the id for the FindById method.

Answer (score 0):

If follow down the implementation, you'll eventually find this method:

```
public virtual Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(TKey userId)
{
  this.ThrowIfDisposed();
  return this.GetUserAggregateAsync((Expression<Func<TUser, bool>>) (u => u.Id.Equals(userId)));
}
```

In order to override this properly, it would have to be inside the `UserStore` class, since there are loads of internal methods (otherwise you'd have to rewrite every single internal method in the class), and add a new Type Parameter that would accept your `ApplicationId`, since `UserStore` is a generic class. Then you would be able to write another `FindByIdAsync` method, because it's a virtual method and it can't be overridden. You would also have to rewrite the `GetUserAggregateAsync` internal method, because it isn't prepared to handle your new  Type Parameter.

Now, there are probably a few more hiccups that would show up, but you can, ultimately, rewrite this method to suit you, but I would advise against it because it's A LOT of work to achieve something that might be possible in another way.

Docs: http://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNet/Identity/EntityFramework/UserStore-TUser-TRole-TContext-TKey/index.html

Code: https://github.com/aspnet/identity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/UserStore.cs